# define macro with conditional evaluation in C/C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

is there a way/trick to make a #define directive evaluate some condition?
for example

```
#define COM_TIME_DO(COND, BODY) \
    #if (COND) BODY
    #else
    #endif
```

it's ok also to use template but body must be an arbitrary (correct in the context is used to) piece of code, simply just present or not in the source depending of COND.

as it is now the previous code doesn't even compile.

the goal of this question is primarly a better knowledge of the language and what i'm trying to do is define a debug macro system that i can activate selectively on certain parts of code for example:

A.hpp

```
#define A_TEST_1 1
#define A_TEST_2 0

Class A {
    ...
    COM_TIME_DO(A_TEST_1,
    void test_method_1();
    )

    COM_TIME_DO(A_TEST_2,
    void test_method_2();
    )

};
```

A.cpp

```
COM_TIME_DO(A_TEST_1,
void A::test_method_1() {
    ...
})

COM_TIME_DO(A_TEST_2,
void A::test_method_2() {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Did you try? What happens when you use the one you posted?

Comment: I think it depends on what `COND` is. Is it a compile time expression or not? Can you elaborate that?

Comment: No it's not possible. For one thing, the preprocessor is line-based, each preprocessor directive is one single line, you can't have multiple directives on a single line, and macros are expanded to a single line.

Comment: please pick one language. And please explain what you need this for. In C++ you can have code discarded at compile time based on a constexpr condition, all without macros.

Comment: It all depends on what `COND` is. If it's a simple macro defined either to `0` or `1`, then yes, it's possible. But there's no way to have an expression in there.

Comment: Soooo just do `#define COM_TIME_DO(COND, BODY)  if(COND) { BODY } `? What are the possible values of `COND`? Please give more contetx.

Comment: somehow its a symptom of macro questions that very often they stay silent about the actual problem that should be solved. Rather than "can i write a macro that does Y?" you should tell us about the actual problem X you want to solve by such macro ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: COND must be a compile time expression

Comment: i know that for that specific problem there could be more than one workaround and i'm happy to see your suggestions. nonetheless that problem raised the doubt if such kind of macro could be done

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: *"compile time expression"* So, not just a `0`/`1` macro? Not possible then. Unclear why you can't just use `#if`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry, i'm still learning how to use stackoverflow and thanks for your suggestions

Comment: How is writing `COM_TIME_DO(A_TEST_2,
void A::test_method_2() {
    ...
})` a lot simpler than writing `#if A_TEST_2
void A::test_method_2() {
    ...
}
#endif`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i cannot use #if because i suspect that i should rewrite the macro for every #if test

Comment: I would not call it "workaround" to not use a macro for this specific case, because there are many ways to get what you want wihtout macros, and they are all simpler, easier to read and maintain, and are not in danger of raising discussions about using macros. Its a little backwards, but yes, the fact that many don't like macros, is one big reason to not use them

Comment: *"i suspect that i should rewrite the macro for every #if test"* No idea what this means.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it means that if i want to use that macro for N piece of code i've to write #if TEST_DEFINE_X BODY #endif N times. i know that's a solution, i was just trying to understand the macro system and look if there was a way of writing it as MACRO_NAME(COND, BODY)

Comment: How is this different from writing `COM_TIME_DO` N times?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is neither different nor better, i was just asking if it was POSSIBLE because i like it more than the #if ... #endif. thanks anyway.

Comment: From the source examples shown you seem to target a flexible testing framework, which allows you to select the tests to run. This is your X problem, but you strive to use a Y solution with stacked macros. Why don't you simply use one of the existing frameworks? Did you try to use the optimizer of your compiler and the features of moden C++? Even if some macro magic is possible, as a reviewer I would reject such source. A change requires to recompile everything, which is a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i was just asking if it was POSSIBLE because i like it more than the #if ... #endif.

If the expression of the condition will always expand to `1` or `0` (or some other *known* set of values) it is possible to implement such a macro.

```
#define VALUE_0(...)
#define VALUE_1(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define COM_TIME_DO_IN(A, ...)  VALUE_##A(__VA_ARGS__)
#define COM_TIME_DO(A, ...)  COM_TIME_DO_IN(A, __VA_ARGS__)
```

However, do not use such code in real life. Use `#if` and write clear, readable and maintainable code that is easy to understand for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way/trick to make a #define directive evaluate some condition?

This depends on what the condition actually is.
Since you mentioned `#if` I'm assuming you'd like to evaluate an integer constant expressions.

Doing this in a macro single macro isn't possible, without implementation defined `_Pragma`s, but you can do it with an `include` + a macro definition:

```
#define COM_TIME_DO ((1 > 2), true, false)
#include "com-time-do.h"
// ^-- generates: false
#define COM_TIME_DO ((1 == 1), true_func();, false_func();)
#include "com-time-do.h"
// ^-- generates: true_func();
```

where `com-time-do.h` is defined as follows:

```
// com-time-do.h
#define SCAN(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define SLOT_AT_COND(a,b,c) a
#define SLOT_AT_THEN(a,b,c) b
#define SLOT_AT_ELSE(a,b,c) c

#if SCAN(SLOT_AT_COND COM_TIME_DO)
SCAN(SLOT_AT_THEN COM_TIME_DO)
#else
SCAN(SLOT_AT_ELSE COM_TIME_DO)
#endif
#undef COM_TIME_DO
```

Although, as KamilCuk said, please write reasonable code and don't use this.